# dynamically adding more values to an arraylist in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

still a bit new with arrays and lists in java, I would like add elements to a list dynamically, so for example if I had code like this:

```
List<int[]> rowList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

rowList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
rowList.add(new int[] { 4, 5, 6 });
rowList.add(new int[] { 7, 8 });
```

how would I dynamically add 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc? thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I am not sure I understand. 
Do you want to keep a List of int[] or a list of int?
When you say "dynamically add 1,2,3,4,5,6,7", do you mean to add them as an array or add them singularly?

Comment: Would you like to add another array, or add numbers to one of the arrays? You can do the former just as you did three times: `rowList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 });`. The latter cannot be done, as an array's length is immutable as soon as it is created.

Comment: Your code is valid. It will add the three int arrays to your list. You cannot add the individual values to that list, since it is a list of int arrays. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `List<Integer>` to store the numbers directly:

```
 List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ints.add(1);    // works with Java 1.5+, inboxing
 ints.add(2);
```

Or, if you want to keep your datastructure, wrap the numbers in short arrays:

```
 rowList.add(newValue(1));
```

where we have:

```
 private int[] newValue(int a) {
    int[] result = new int[1];
    result[0] = a;
    return result;
 }
```

**Edit**

Some more Java 1.5+ magic, using varargs and autoboxing:

```
 private int[] newValue(Integer... values) {
    int[] result = new int[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
       result[i] = values[i];
    return result
 }
```

**Usage:**

```
List<int[]> rowList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

rowList.add(newValues(10, 20, 30));
rowList.add(newValues(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
```

Comment: (hope I understood what you wanted to achieve ;) )

Comment: Funny, did you introduce varargs after my solution or before? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new int[] to the list you will first have to create and fill it. If you don't know the length the array will be I would suggest an array that will dynamically add space as your reach its limit.

After you have created this array, just pass it as an argument. Should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop if you would like to add them without writing out every single number.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [however many you would like]; i++) {
    ints.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something of this effect (using [`varargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) if you have JDK 5 and higher).

```
public class ListUtils {
    public static void add(List<int[]> list, int... args) {
        if (list != null && args != null) {
            list.add(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can do

```
ListUtils.add(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you need but I hope this example will help you :

```
List<Integer> rowList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(rowList, ArrayUtils.toObject(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Collections.addAll(rowList, ArrayUtils.toObject(new int[] { 4, 5, 6 }));
Collections.addAll(rowList, ArrayUtils.toObject(new int[] { 7, 8 }));
```

ArraysUtils is a class of apache commons really usefull to deal with primitive and object arrays.

Regards,
Diodfr